# Iterable class in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How to define iterable class in Flow?

Following code (in [try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDG0CGBnToCCoBvRUUAbQGUBPAWwCNZoA6ASwBcBTAJ3Vdk4F0AFAEoAXKACSHbr04AeTK07MAdgHMAfIWIlQndqwCunFdt26V7AB6sRZ3QEh9Rk-ZIOSAE1iXxSw+w6Dg4AvjrmYe6RoGEhQA)):

```js
// @flow

class A {
  [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string> {
    return {
      next() {
        return {
          done: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

reports error

```
4:   [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string> {
     ^ computed property keys not supported
```

According to Flow issue [Flow doesn't like Symbols as object keys](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3258) it looks like direct use if symbols is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use some workarounds, but you can define an iterable class. If you look at Flow's [built-in definitions](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js#L565) you can see that Flow internally uses a property called `@@iterator` as a stand-in for `[Symbol.iterator]`. What you have to do is to define both properties on your class: `[Symbol.iterator]` to get runtime iterator functionality, and `@@iterator` so that Flow knows what the class iterator capability is for type-checking.

As you noted Flow will throw an error if you try to define a property `[Symbol.iterator]`. You can get around that using a `// $FlowFixMe` annotation:

```js
// $FlowFixMe
[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string> { /* ... */ }
```

On the other hand `@@iterator` is not a valid property name outside of Flow. For example Babel will throw a syntax error. But `@@iterator` does not need to exist at runtime anyway, so you can define it in a Flow comment so that only Flow sees it. Putting this together you get:

```js
export class A {
  // $FlowFixMe
  [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string> {
    return {
      next() {
        return {
          done: true
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /*::
  @@iterator(): Iterator<string> {
    // $FlowFixMe
    return this[Symbol.iterator]()
  }
  */
}
```

Note the special formatting of that comment: it must begin with exact characters `/*::` to get Flow to interpret the content of the comment as a declaration.