# Flow annotation for iterable and async iterable objects?

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, flowtype

I have a function `foo` that returns an object that can be iterated:

```
const foo = () => ({
  [Symbol.iterator]: function * () {
    yield * [ 1, 2, 3 ]; 
  }, 
});

for (const x of foo()) {
  console.log(x);
}

// 1
// 2
// 3
```

Now I would like to annotate `foo` with Flow type definitions. But what do these look like?

Additionally, what about an `async` version, `bar`?

```
const bar = () => ({
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]: async function * () {
    yield * [ 1, 2, 3 ]; 
  }, 
});

for await (const x of bar()) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: For non-async version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491307/iterable-class-in-flow/48528104#48528104 . I'm not sure if Flow can handle the `for await ...` syntax yet

Comment: Here's a related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3258#issuecomment-361690526